# How Can I display User Uploaded Avatar in Login Form?

Tags: php, wordpress, gravatar, avatars

I'm going to try my best to explain what I'm trying to do here.

I created a login form for my wordpress that lets users login directly from the homepage it includes the Avatar for the profile that's logged in. Here is the code I came up with.

```
<div id="loginDiv">

<!-- If User Is Logged In Display This -->

<?php if (is_user_logged_in()) { ?>

Welcome <strong><?php echo $user_identity ?></strong>.

<?php echo get_avatar($id_or_email,$size='100'); ?>

<form name="loginform" id="loginform" action="<?php echo wp_logout_url(); ?>" method="post">

<input type="submit" name="wp-submit" id="wp-submit" value="LOG OUT" />
<a href="http://www.bignotch.com/wp-admin/profile.php">EDIT YOUR PROFILE</a>

<input type="hidden" name="redirect_to" value="<?php bloginfo('url'); ?>" />
</form>

<!-- If User Is NOT Logged In Display This -->

<? } else { ?>

<form name="loginform" id="loginform" action="<?php bloginfo('url'); ?>/wp-login.php" method="post">

<label for="log">Username</label> <input type="text" name="log" id="user_login" class="input" value="" size="20" tabindex="10" /></p>
<label for="pwd">Password</label> <input type="password" name="pwd" id="user_pass" class="input" value="" size="20" tabindex="20" /></p>

<input type="submit" name="wp-submit" id="wp-submit" value="LOG IN" /> <input type="button" value="SIGNUP" onClick="parent.location='<?php bloginfo('url'); ?>/wp-login.php?action=register'" />

<a href="<?php bloginfo('url'); ?>/wp-login.php?action=lostpassword">Lost your password?</a>

<input type="hidden" name="redirect_to" value="<?php bloginfo('url'); ?>/members" />
<input type="hidden" name="testcookie" value="1" />
</form>

<? } ?></div>
```

The problem here is that wordpress requires users to go to the "gravatar" site in order to create a avatar. This is no good for me. So, I installed the  **Simple Local Avatars** plugin that allows users to upload their own user photos, but I cannot figure out how I can get that image to show up in my custom login form.

The portion of code I use to display the avatar in the login form is:

```
<?php echo get_avatar($id_or_email,$size='100'); ?>
```

But it seems that it tries to grab the Gravatar image. I need this to grab the image that the user uploads. How can i do this?

Edit:

Here is the php code for the **Simple Local Avatar** plugin:

```
class simple_local_avatars 
{
    function simple_local_avatars() {
        add_filter( 'get_avatar', array( $this, 'get_avatar' ), 10, 5 );

        add_action( 'admin_init', array( $this, 'admin_init' ) );

        add_action( 'show_user_profile', array( $this, 'edit_user_profile' ) );
        add_action( 'edit_user_profile', array( $this, 'edit_user_profile' ) );

        add_action( 'personal_options_update', array( $this, 'edit_user_profile_update' ) );
        add_action( 'edit_user_profile_update', array( $this, 'edit_user_profile_update' ) );

        add_filter( 'avatar_defaults', array( $this, 'avatar_defaults' ) );
    }

    function get_avatar( $avatar = '', $id_or_email, $size = '96', $default = '', $alt = false ) {

        if ( is_numeric($id_or_email) )
            $user_id = (int) $id_or_email;
        elseif ( is_string( $id_or_email ) && ( $user = get_user_by_email( $id_or_email ) ) )
            $user_id = $user->ID;
        elseif ( is_object( $id_or_email ) && ! empty( $id_or_email->user_id ) )
            $user_id = (int) $id_or_email->user_id;

        if ( empty( $user_id ) )
            return $avatar;

        $local_avatars = get_user_meta( $user_id, 'simple_local_avatar', true );

        if ( empty( $local_avatars ) || empty( $local_avatars['full'] ) )
            return $avatar;

        $size = (int) $size;

        if ( empty( $alt ) )
            $alt = get_the_author_meta( 'display_name', $user_id );

        // generate a new size
        if ( empty( $local_avatars[$size] ) ) {
            $upload_path = wp_upload_dir();
            $avatar_full_path = str_replace( $upload_path['baseurl'], $upload_path['basedir'], $local_avatars['full'] );
            $image_sized = image_resize( $avatar_full_path, $size, $size, true );

            // deal with original being >= to original image (or lack of sizing ability)
            $local_avatars[$size] = is_wp_error($image_sized) ? $local_avatars[$size] = $local_avatars['full'] : str_replace( $upload_path['basedir'], $upload_path['baseurl'], $image_sized ); 

            update_user_meta( $user_id, 'simple_local_avatar', $local_avatars );
        } elseif ( substr( $local_avatars[$size], 0, 4 ) != 'http' ) {
            $local_avatars[$size] = site_url( $local_avatars[$size] );
        }

        $author_class = is_author( $user_id ) ? ' current-author' : '' ;
        $avatar = "<img alt='" . esc_attr($alt) . "' src='" . $local_avatars[$size] . "' class='avatar avatar-{$size}{$author_class} photo' height='{$size}' width='{$size}' />";

        return apply_filters( 'simple_local_avatar', $avatar );
    }

    function admin_init() {
        load_plugin_textdomain( 'simple-local-avatars', false, dirname( plugin_basename( __FILE__ ) ) . '/localization/' );

        register_setting( 'discussion', 'simple_local_avatars_caps', array( $this, 'sanitize_options' ) );
        add_settings_field( 'simple-local-avatars-caps', __('Local Avatar Permissions','simple-local-avatars'), array( $this, 'avatar_settings_field' ), 'discussion', 'avatars' );
    }

    function sanitize_options( $input ) {
        $new_input['simple_local_avatars_caps'] = empty( $input['simple_local_avatars_caps'] ) ? 0 : 1;
        return $new_input;
    }

    function avatar_settings_field( $args ) {       
        $options = get_option('simple_local_avatars_caps');

        echo '
            <label for="simple_local_avatars_caps">
                <input type="checkbox" name="simple_local_avatars_caps" id="simple_local_avatars_caps" value="1" ' . @checked( $options['simple_local_avatars_caps'], 1, false ) . ' />
                ' . __('Only allow users with file upload capabilities to upload local avatars (Authors and above)','simple-local-avatars') . '
            </label>
        ';
    }

    function edit_user_profile( $profileuser ) {
    ?>
    <h3><?php _e( 'Avatar','simple-local-avatars' ); ?></h3>

    <table class="form-table">
        <tr>
            <th><label for="simple-local-avatar"><?php _e('Upload Avatar','simple-local-avatars'); ?></label></th>
            <td style="width: 50px;" valign="top">
                <?php echo get_avatar( $profileuser->ID ); ?>
            </td>
            <td>
            <?php
                $options = get_option('simple_local_avatars_caps');

                if ( empty($options['simple_local_avatars_caps']) || current_user_can('upload_files') ) {
                    do_action( 'simple_local_avatar_notices' ); 
                    wp_nonce_field( 'simple_local_avatar_nonce', '_simple_local_avatar_nonce', false ); 
            ?>
                    <input type="file" name="simple-local-avatar" id="simple-local-avatar" /><br />
            <?php
                    if ( empty( $profileuser->simple_local_avatar ) )
                        echo '<span class="description">' . __('No local avatar is set. Use the upload field to add a local avatar.','simple-local-avatars') . '</span>';
                    else 
                        echo '
                            <input type="checkbox" name="simple-local-avatar-erase" value="1" /> ' . __('Delete local avatar','simple-local-avatars') . '<br />
                            <span class="description">' . __('Replace the local avatar by uploading a new avatar, or erase the local avatar (falling back to a gravatar) by checking the delete option.','simple-local-avatars') . '</span>
                        ';      
                } else {
                    if ( empty( $profileuser->simple_local_avatar ) )
                        echo '<span class="description">' . __('No local avatar is set. Set up your avatar at Gravatar.com.','simple-local-avatars') . '</span>';
                    else 
                        echo '<span class="description">' . __('You do not have media management permissions. To change your local avatar, contact the blog administrator.','simple-local-avatars') . '</span>';
                }
            ?>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    <script type="text/javascript">var form = document.getElementById('your-profile');form.encoding = 'multipart/form-data';form.setAttribute('enctype', 'multipart/form-data');</script>
    <?php       
    }

    function edit_user_profile_update( $user_id ) {
        if ( ! isset( $_POST['_simple_local_avatar_nonce'] ) || ! wp_verify_nonce( $_POST['_simple_local_avatar_nonce'], 'simple_local_avatar_nonce' ) )            //security
            return;

        if ( ! empty( $_FILES['simple-local-avatar']['name'] ) ) {
            $mimes = array(
                'jpg|jpeg|jpe' => 'image/jpeg',
                'gif' => 'image/gif',
                'png' => 'image/png',
                'bmp' => 'image/bmp',
                'tif|tiff' => 'image/tiff'
            );

            // front end (theme my profile etc) support
            if ( ! function_exists( 'wp_handle_upload' ) )
                require_once( ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/file.php' );

            $this->avatar_delete( $user_id );   // delete old images if successful

            $avatar = wp_handle_upload( $_FILES['simple-local-avatar'], array( 'mimes' => $mimes, 'test_form' => false, 'unique_filename_callback' => array( $this, 'unique_filename_callback' ) ) );

            if ( empty($avatar['file']) ) {     // handle failures
                switch ( $avatar['error'] ) {
                    case 'File type does not meet security guidelines. Try another.' :
                        add_action( 'user_profile_update_errors', create_function('$a','$a->add("avatar_error",__("Please upload a valid image file for the avatar.","simple-local-avatars"));') );             
                        break;
                    default :
                        add_action( 'user_profile_update_errors', create_function('$a','$a->add("avatar_error","<strong>".__("There was an error uploading the avatar:","simple-local-avatars")."</strong> ' . esc_attr( $avatar['error'] ) . '");') );
                }

                return;
            }

            update_user_meta( $user_id, 'simple_local_avatar', array( 'full' => $avatar['url'] ) );     // save user information (overwriting old)
        } elseif ( ! empty( $_POST['simple-local-avatar-erase'] ) ) {
            $this->avatar_delete( $user_id );
        }
    }

    /**
     * remove the custom get_avatar hook for the default avatar list output on options-discussion.php
     */
    function avatar_defaults( $avatar_defaults ) {
        remove_action( 'get_avatar', array( $this, 'get_avatar' ) );
        return $avatar_defaults;
    }

    /**
     * delete avatars based on user_id
     */
    function avatar_delete( $user_id ) {
        $old_avatars = get_user_meta( $user_id, 'simple_local_avatar', true );
        $upload_path = wp_upload_dir();

        if ( is_array($old_avatars) ) {
            foreach ($old_avatars as $old_avatar ) {
                $old_avatar_path = str_replace( $upload_path['baseurl'], $upload_path['basedir'], $old_avatar );
                @unlink( $old_avatar_path );    
            }
        }

        delete_user_meta( $user_id, 'simple_local_avatar' );
    }

    function unique_filename_callback( $dir, $name, $ext ) {
        $user = wp_get_current_user();
        $name = sanitize_file_name( $user->display_name . '_avatar' );

        $number = 1;

        while ( file_exists( $dir . "/$name$ext" ) ) {
            $name = $name . '_' . $number;
            $number++;
        }

        return $name . $ext;
    }
}

$simple_local_avatars = new simple_local_avatars;

/**
 * more efficient to call simple local avatar directly in theme and avoid gravatar setup
 * 
 * @param int|string|object $id_or_email A user ID,  email address, or comment object
 * @param int $size Size of the avatar image
 * @param string $default URL to a default image to use if no avatar is available
 * @param string $alt Alternate text to use in image tag. Defaults to blank
 * @return string <img> tag for the user's avatar
 */
function get_simple_local_avatar( $id_or_email, $size = '96', $default = '', $alt = false ) {
    global $simple_local_avatars;
    $avatar = $simple_local_avatars->get_avatar( '', $id_or_email, $size, $default, $alt );

    if ( empty ( $avatar ) )
        $avatar = get_avatar( $id_or_email, $size, $default, $alt );

    return $avatar;
}

/**
 * on uninstallation, remove the custom field from the users and delete the local avatars
 */

register_uninstall_hook( __FILE__, 'simple_local_avatars_uninstall' );

function simple_local_avatars_uninstall() {
    $simple_local_avatars = new simple_local_avatars;
    $users = get_users_of_blog();

    foreach ( $users as $user )
        $simple_local_avatars->avatar_delete( $user->user_id );

    delete_option('simple_local_avatars_caps');
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of using

```
echo get_avatar($id_or_email,$size='100');
```

Try calling this

global $current_user;

echo get_avatar($current_user->id,100);

Comment: I tried this, but it just grabs the wordpress gravatar and not the **Simple Local Avatars* avatar image. I've been looking at some of the variables in the wordpress plugin and putting together different strings of code.. nothing so far.

Comment: If you use global $current_user; before the line you want to echo the avatar and the user uploads a pic from wp profile page in the backend,It will use that. Please try by using the same code and making sure to upload a fresh image.(Also check if you are using any caching solutions)

Comment: YES!!!!  That did it!!!  It goes without saying that you are the BEST man!  I spent hours trying to understand the script enough to come up with working code for this. Apparently, I need to study a bit more. Thanks for this!

Comment: glad it helped:) btw, if you want to avoid using the global you can replace `$current_user->id` with `get_current_user_id()` like `echo get_avatar(get_current_user_id(),100);`

Answer (score 1):

first you need to hook the plugins between simple local avatar and bbpress to do that add

this line within bbpress theme folder(which ever theme you using) bbpress-functions.php inside setup actions()

`add_action( 'bbp_sla_edit_user_profile', array( 'simple_local_avatars', 'edit_user_profile' ) );`

add this line in form-user-edit.php of bbpress theme folder

`<?php 
        global $current_user;
        do_action( 'bbp_sla_edit_user_profile', $current_user ); 
?>`